# Displaying distinct count as separate column for each value returned

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, inner-join

Table1 (contains order source type information)

```
id | name
---------
 0 | App
 1 | Web
```

Table2 (contains orders information)

```
order_id | date_ordered | source_id 
   0     |   24/04/2016 |    0
   1     |   24/04/2016 |    1
   2     |   23/04/2016 |    0
   3     |   23/04/2016 |    1
   4     |   23/04/2016 |    0
   5     |   22/04/2016 |    1
   6     |   22/04/2016 |    0
```

I want to display count of orders from each source on a given date

```
Date       | Source Count 0 | Source Count 1
24/04/2016 |       1        |       1
23/04/2016 |       2        |       1
22/04/2016 |       1        |       1
```

The query I came up with as far as now:

```
SELECT
    date_ordered,
    count(distinct),
FROM `event`
 INNER JOIN `Table1`
    ON `id` = `Table2`.`source_id`
 GROUP BY date_ordered
ORDER BY date_ordered desc
```

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out, and couldn't came up with anything better. Problem is that number of sources are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use case and group by

```
 select date_ordered, 
 case when source_id = 0 then sum(source_id)
 END as  'Source Count 0',    
 case when source_id = 1 then sum(source_id)
 END as  'Source Count 1'
 group by date_ordered
```

Comment: that would be good if sources were static. Pre execution of the query I don't know how many sources possibly can be in the table.